# Change empty view of ListView

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I'm using a ListView with a custom adapter to receive a JSON response and put it into a nice list - works great.

I'm now testing various exceptions and error handling and am catching errors received from my web API within the Android app. This all works great, handles well - but for the life of me I can't work out how to change the 'empty view' of a ListView once it has been set once.

It's within a fragment, if that makes any difference - but the ProgressBar and ListView are defined in an XML layout which is inflated in the Fragment. I have a TextView also inside there which contains some error text - I want to know how to switch the ProgressBar out for the TextView onError()!

Edit: Currently the ListView uses the ProgressBar as the empty view - I want to know how to later change this to another view - XML defined or programmatic.

The UI thread is not being locked as all API calls are carried out on an AsyncTask, so that's not the issue.

ListView.removeAllViews() caused a fairly imminent crash.

Apologies if this is trivial...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could define the empty view to be a FrameLayout and put whatever you want the empty state be inside that view and change it the way you'd change contents of any other view.

Comment: Pretty much went with this approach (used RelativeLayout) - thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I have two empty views for my ListView. One is ProgressBar which I shows while I am loading data from database or server. Other is TextView, which I shows when I got error or have no data.

I put my ListView, ProgressBar and TextView in FrameLayout. And set visibility of both ProgressBar and TextView to Gone.

```
    <FrameLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <ListView 
            android:id="@+id/my_listview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/empty_textview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:text="@string/no_contacts_found"/>

        <ProgressBar 
            android:id="@+id/empty_progressbar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:indeterminate="true"/>

    </FrameLayout>
```

Before loading data from database or server, I change visibility of ProgressBar to Visible and set it as empty view of my ListView. So my ListView starts showing ProgressBar, indicating user that data is still loading.

If I got error or got no data from database or server, I set visibility of ProgressBar to Gone and change visibility of TextView to Visible. And then set TextView as empty view of my ListView.

Answer (score 0):

I just found this code in an old project, should work fine:

```
View emptyView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.id_of_your_layoout_file, parent, false);
getListView.setEmptyView(emptyView);
```

Comment: This isn't in onCreateView though, so fetching inflater etc. is complicated. Am I approaching this incorrectly?

I've got:

`void displayError(){
  ListView lv = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.my_list_view);
  lv.setEmptyView(R.id.failed_text);
}`

Inside the fragment class.

Comment: Approached this differently and used a larger layout for the empty view - a RelativeLayout with a ProgressBar and "Loading..." text TextView.

Upon error, simply:

    TextView failed = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.failed_text_view);
    failed.setText(R.string.failed_to_load);

You could probably just hide the TextView until error, if you wanted that effect.

Thanks for the quick responses.